# The Python spacy module not working on Apache

Tags: python, django, apache, spacy

I have a Django application running on Apache24 in Windows. I am using Python 3.9.5. The application works fine. But after installing the spacy module and importing it on a Python file as follows,

```
import spacy
```

the application is hanging and the Apache no longer responses. The spacy module works fine with Django's server (python manage.py runserver)

My settings are fine. But in case you wonder, here are some of them.

In the settings.py file:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost']
```

In the C:\Apache24\conf\httpd.conf file

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

LoadFile "c:/users/administrator/appdata/local/programs/python/python39/python39.dll"
LoadModule wsgi_module "c:/users/administrator/appdata/local/programs/python/python39/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp39-win_amd64.pyd"

WSGIScriptAlias / "C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py"
WSGIPythonHome "c:/users/administrator/appdata/local/programs/python/python39"
WSGIPythonPath "C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/myproject/"

Alias /static C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/myproject/static

<Directory C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/myproject/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/myproject/myproject/>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

Any idea why the spacy module doesn't work on the Apache server and how to fix it?

Comment: Did you check the logs? Can you post them in the question?

Comment: The logs don't show anything.

Comment: Can you import spaCy in Python outside of your server? Without more details it's really hard to say what's wrong...

Comment: Yes, I can import spaCy in other webservers such as nginx, or django's local server but it doesn't work on the Apache server. Just start a new django project, install/import spaCy and try to run it on the Apache. Then, you'll see what I mean. I had to switch to nginx on the production site.